# Write for loop with same function as foreach

Tags: c#, loops

I have my foreach loop:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (DataRow data in result.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     var periodStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data.Table.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString().Remove(10));
     var periodEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data.Table.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString().Remove(0, 12));
     calc.PeriodStartDate = periodStartDate;
     calc.PeriodEndDate = periodEndDate;
     calc.InvoiceAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Invoice amount"].ToString());
     calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Interest rate"].ToString());
     calc.InterestAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Interest amount"].ToString());
     calc.Amortization = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Amortization"].ToString());
     calc.PresentValue = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Capital balance"].ToString());
     calc.StartValue = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[0]["Capital balance"].ToString());
     cList.Add(calc);
     i++;
}
```

I wanna do the same but in a for loop instead. Tried this (don't work because it can't find data (obviously):

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
     var periodStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data.Table.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString().Remove(10));
     var periodEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data.Table.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString().Remove(0, 12));
     calc.PeriodStartDate = periodStartDate;
     calc.PeriodEndDate = periodEndDate;
     calc.InvoiceAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Invoice amount"].ToString());
     calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Interest rate"].ToString());
     calc.InterestAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Interest amount"].ToString());
     calc.Amortization = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Amortization"].ToString());
     calc.PresentValue = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Capital balance"].ToString());
     calc.StartValue = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[0]["Capital balance"].ToString());
     cList.Add(calc);
}
```

How can I re-write my for loop so it matches my foreach loop?

Comment: Wait, what? You're using a `foreach` over the `Rows` so that you could take the *table* and then iterate over *its* rows using an indexer? Why aren't you simply doing `data["Date"]` etc. in your `foreach` code?

Comment: I didn't now that worked..

Comment: Also, note that you *have* to create a new instance of `calc` in each iteration of the loop (unless it's a `struct`), otherwise you'll have a nice list of completely identical values in `cList`. And of course, there's no reason to convert the value to string and then to a given data type - you can cast it right away, eg. `(decimal)row["Capital balance"]`.

Comment: @Luaan When I use data["Date"] I get "Input string was not a correct format". So that doesn't work for me

Comment: Well, for a date, you'd obviously have to use `(DateTime)data["Date"]`. Assuming you do actually have a structure in the data table. If it's all made of strings, you're going to have to do the parsing (but you still should do a cast, rather than `ToString`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the DataRow for each iteration .

Add the following statement in forloop as first statement:

```
DataRow data = result.Tables[0].Rows[i];
```

**Complete Code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
     DataRow data = result.Tables[0].Rows[i];
     var periodStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data.Table.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString().Remove(10));
     var periodEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data.Table.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString().Remove(0, 12));
     calc.PeriodStartDate = periodStartDate;
     calc.PeriodEndDate = periodEndDate;
     calc.InvoiceAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Invoice amount"].ToString());
     calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Interest rate"].ToString());
     calc.InterestAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Interest amount"].ToString());
     calc.Amortization = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Amortization"].ToString());
     calc.PresentValue = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[i]["Capital balance"].ToString());
     calc.StartValue = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[0]["Capital balance"].ToString());
     cList.Add(calc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In first place you're using `foreach` itself wrong. You already have `DataRow` and still you're having a counter, etc etc they are not required.

```
foreach (DataRow data in result.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     var periodStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data["Date"].ToString().Remove(10));
     //You can simplify rest like this with `data`
}

for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{    
    DataRow data = result.Tables[0].Rows[i];
    var periodStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data["Date"].ToString().Remove(10)); 
    //And so on   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = result.Tables[0];

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     var periodStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString()
                                  .Remove(10));
     var periodEndDate   = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString()
                                  .Remove(0, 12));

     // And the rest of the fields...

     cList.Add(calc);
}
```

Or, of course, you can simply use LINQ:

```
var cList = 
  result.Tables[0].Rows.Select
  (
    (row, index) =>
    {
      var calc = new YourCalc();

      calc.Something = row["SomeField"] as SomeType;

      return calc;
    }
  ).ToList();
```